# Angular Material 6 override input/select style

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to override the colors on my material input elements to always be white.  This includes the outline of the input/select field, the placeholder, and the text itself even when the field is out of focus.

I did read through the official material overriding styles guide, but I found it a bit broad and was hoping for some more direction to do this.

This is my code:

```
<mat-card class="coverage-card">
 <mat-card-content>
   <form>
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="address-zip white-text">
       <mat-label>Square Footage</mat-label>
       <input type="number" matInput>
     </mat-form-field>
   </form>
 </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

css styles:

```
.coverage-card{
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 620px;    
    background-color: #FF6A13;
    height: 575px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.address-zip{
    max-width: 190px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.white-text{
    color: white;
}
```

The out-of-box material color only applies when the field is focused on.  I haven't been able to find the style that is being applied to the outline or placeholder when the field isn't in focus.

I tried overriding classes like .mat-form-field-appearance-outline in styles.scss with an !important, just to see if I could find the right class and haven't had any luck yet.

[Not in Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19RYb.jpg)

[Focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdh5v.jpg)

[Filled In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8nDW.jpg)

Comment: Although it may seems complicate, is not difficult to create a custom angular material theme to solve this. I would suggest you to either: 1) create a custom theme and [apply it specifically to the input](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#theming-only-certain-components). This will affect all inputs 2) create a custom theme and [use a class to apply it or not](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes) (this way you may apply different themes dynamically to your inputs)